# Webservice in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, vba, web-services, excel-2013

I want to call a web-service from excel 2013, where in I pass the parameter values from the excel sheet. How can this be achieved without using VBA, also this is specific to Excel 2013. If I have to use VBA, then how do I proceed in Excel 2013.

thanks..

Comment: I doubt excel will run Java so you'd at least need some VBA script to call a a Java application - in which case you could probably do the call in VBA entirely. Also have a look here: https://blogs.office.com/2013/03/21/use-webservice-functions-to-automatically-update-excel-2013-spreadsheets-with-online-data/

Comment: In Excel 2013 it should be possible with new function [WebService()](http://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2012/07/31/using-the-webservice-function-in-excel-2013/). Usage: ```=WEBSERVICE(“http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/&#8221; & ENCODEURL(E2) & “/3dayforecast.rss”)```.